# Complete date series grouped by another column in pandas and fill missing rows

Tags: python, pandas, date

I have data set with a particular ID.
For particular ID I want to complete the date series.
So, for ex: if I have the max date in dataset as : '2020-06-01'(YYYY-MM-DD) and min date as : '2020-03-01'
How do I fill missing rows while filling in value of attribute columns

```
    ID  sale_month   attribute1    attribute2
0   1   2020-06-01    blue              1
1   1   2020-05-01    blue              2
2   1   2020-04-01    blue              3
3   1   2020-03-01    blue              4
4   2   2020-05-01    yellow            5
5   2   2020-04-01    yellow            4
6   2   2020-03-01    yellow            3
7   3   2020-05-01    green             7
8   3   2020-04-01    green             8
```

I'd like to achieve this :

```
    ID  sale_month   attribute1    attribute2
0   1   2020-06-01    blue              1
1   1   2020-05-01    blue              2
2   1   2020-04-01    blue              3
3   1   2020-03-01    blue              4
4   2   2020-06-01    yellow            6
5   2   2020-05-01    yellow            5
6   2   2020-04-01    yellow            4
7   2   2020-03-01    yellow            3
8   3   2020-06-01    green             6
9   3   2020-05-01    green             7
10  3   2020-04-01    green             8
11  3   2020-03-01    green             9
```

I can do it when there's no ID-based grouping by indexing on the date column and then reindexing and using interpolation to fill in values.
How do I do that here with the grouping column? And also, can I use different methods of interpolation for different columns. For example, duplicating `attribute1`, but linear interpolation in `attribute2`.

To duplicate the data frame :

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3], 
                   'sale_month' : ['2020-06-01', '2020-05-01', '2020-04-01', '2020-03-01', '2020-05-01', '2020-04-01', '2020-03-01', '2020-05-01', '2020-04-01'],
                   'attribute1': [ 'blue', 'blue', 'blue', 'blue', 'yellow', 'yellow', 'yellow', 'green', 'green'],
                   'attribute2' : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 3, 7, 8 ]})
df.sale_month = pd.to_datetime(df.sale_month)
```

Comment: *linear interpolation* is not really applicable in your case, where the missing data are not in the range of available data, e.g. in the case of `green`.

Comment: Ohkay, yeah, for that case it'd be extrapolation.
To keep matters simple, we can restrict one column to one type of missing value treatment for now. Like interpolation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `MultiIndex.from_product` with `pd.date_range`:

```
dates = pd.date_range(df["sale_month"].min(), df["sale_month"].max(), freq="MS")

s = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df["ID"].unique(), reversed(dates)],names=df.columns[:2])

df = df.set_index(["ID","sale_month"]).reindex(s).reset_index()

df["attribute1"] = df.groupby('ID')["attribute1"].transform("first")

print (df)

    ID sale_month attribute1  attribute2
0    1 2020-06-01       blue         1.0
1    1 2020-05-01       blue         2.0
2    1 2020-04-01       blue         3.0
3    1 2020-03-01       blue         4.0
4    2 2020-06-01     yellow         NaN
5    2 2020-05-01     yellow         5.0
6    2 2020-04-01     yellow         4.0
7    2 2020-03-01     yellow         3.0
8    3 2020-06-01      green         NaN
9    3 2020-05-01      green         7.0
10   3 2020-04-01      green         8.0
11   3 2020-03-01      green         NaN
```

Comment: Excellent answer. Learned a lot. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Multiindex is what I was expecting too.
Similarly to your transform(first) are their other function that can be used with transform?

Comment: A number of methods are supported, e.g. `cumsum`, `sum`, `last`, `mean`.. basically all aggregate functions can be applied.